# getting type error while iterating values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that returns a position on a board (starting from position 0) for each roll of a dice.

My dictionary contains keys, which are the positions on the board
and values, which are the

displacements that should take place.

```
dictionary = {64: -4, 49: -38, 98: -20, 16: -10, 87: -63, 56: -3, 47: -21, 93: -20, 62: -43, 
              95: -20, 80: 20, 1: 37, 51: 16, 4: 10, 21: 21, 71: 20, 9: 22, 28: 56, 36: 8}
```

For example, when I land on position 64, I find key 64 in the dictionary and from 64 I move -4 on the board, resting on 60.

I have my current code below.

```
def location(rolls):
dictionary = {64: -4, 49: -38, 98: -20, 16: -10, 87: -63, 56: -3, 47: -21, 93: -20, 62: -43, 
              95: -20, 80: 20, 1: 37, 51: 16, 4: 10, 21: 21, 71: 20, 9: 22, 28: 56, 36: 8}

    position = 0
    list_position = []
    for roll in rolls:
        position = position + roll

        if position not in dictionary:
            pass
        if position in dictionary:
            position = position + dictionary.get(roll)
            list_position.append(position)
        print(position)
```

I am getting partial positions and I believe some iterations are returning a type error.

```
>>> location([1, 4, 5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 12, in location
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
38
42

# desired output
[38, 42, 26]
```

From the first roll of the dice, we land on position 1. We located 1 in my dictionary and learned that I

have to move by 37, resting on 38. From the second roll of the dice, we move 4 from 38 and land

on 42. 42 is not in my dictionary, so we rest on 42. Then from the third roll of the dice, we move 5

from 42, landing on 47. 47 is in my dictionary and I move -21 from 47, landing on 26.

So I am actually getting the first two positions in the list. I have not a single clue why the third

position is not being printed and returning this type error.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It is not possible to see what `location` was intended to do

Comment: well `5` isn't in the dict so `dictionary.get(roll)` returns `None`, which can't be added to an integer

Comment: @Ayxan I have fixed the indentation.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Oh I see. 4 and 1 are in dict, but 5 is not. Haven't I cleared the case with pass statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think `list_position` and `position_list` were meant to be the same lists
2. `5` isn't in the dictionary (since you are not checking for `roll`, you are only checking for `position`), so it returns `None` and you definitely cannot add `None` to an integer. Add a default value for non-existent keys.
3. <del>A minor suggestion; the `if` case with `pass` you used there does almost nothing. You might only check for the case the key is in the dictionary.</del>

EDIT: Looks like what OP meant to do was `dictionary.get(position)`. In that case we don't need to check for anything.

Here's what I mean:

```
def location(rolls):
  dictionary = {64: -4, 49: -38, 98: -20, 16: -10, 87: -63, 56: -3, 47: -21, 93: -20, 62: -43, 
              95: -20, 80: 20, 1: 37, 51: 16, 4: 10, 21: 21, 71: 20, 9: 22, 28: 56, 36: 8}

  position = 0
  list_position = []
  for roll in rolls:
    position = position + roll
    # if position not in dictionary:  # commented out
    #     pass                        # 
    # if position in dictionary:      # no need to check anything since default is 0
    position = position + dictionary.get(position, 0)
    list_position.append(position)    # fixed the name
    print(position)
```

Run it:

```
location([1, 4, 5])
```

Output:

```
38
42
26
```

Comment: The last output should be 26, not 47 btw. Why would this be returning 42 + 5 and not 26?

Comment: @VAnon Well, in that case what you meant to do was `dictionary.get(position, 0)` instead of `dictionary.get(roll, 0)`. Edited and fixed that.

Comment: @VAnon in that case, you don't need the `if` cases at all

Answer (score 2):

Your code have some structuring issue:

1. The checks should be one big `if` block instead of 2 separate ones:

   ```
   if position not in dictionary:
       pass
   else:   # <-- use else instead
       position = position + dictionary.get(roll)
       list_position.append(position)
   print(position)
   ```

Since the two conditions are polar opposites there's no point for you to do another `position in dictionary` check.

Better yet - since you don't even need to do anything if `position not in dictionary`, just do this:

```
if position in dictionary:
    position = position + dictionary.get(roll)
    list_position.append(position)
# you don't need an else because you don't intend to do anything
```

2. The `dictionary.get(roll)` is not controlled by the condition.  You would check if `position in dictionary` but you do not ensure that `roll` is also in `dictionary`.  Therefore when it's not in there, `dict.get()` returns `None` by default.

You can either set a default value like `dictionary.get(roll, 0)`, or fill your dictionary with all the possible rolls you want to define, or do a check for `roll in dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `position = position + dictionary.get(roll)`. On the 3rd iteration where the roll is = 5, dictionary.get(roll) evaluates to None.

EDIT: Also, if you want to skip to the next iteration of the for loop, the proper syntax is continue, not pass.

I added a check for this below:

```
def location(rolls):
    dictionary = {64: -4, 49: -38, 98: -20, 16: -10, 87: -63, 56: -3, 47: -21, 93: -20, 62: -43,
                  95: -20, 80: 20, 1: 37, 51: 16, 4: 10, 21: 21, 71: 20, 9: 22, 28: 56, 36: 8}
    position = 0
    list_position = []
    for roll in rolls:
        position = position + roll
        if position not in dictionary:
            continue # pass does nothing here
        if position in dictionary:
            if dictionary.get(roll):
                position = position + dictionary.get(roll)
            list_position.append(position)
        print(position)

location([1, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Just use `position = position + dictionary.get(roll, 0)` and remove the extra `if dictionary.get(roll):`: not necessary to fetch the same key twice.